# How to Slow the Speed of a Sewing Machine

Tags: sewing, sewing-machine

I recently purchased Singer Start 1304 Sewing Machine. When I press on the foot ever so lightly it goes fast and loud.

I am really taken aback by so much noise and speed (especially since I am new comer and have now figured out how thread properly and make straight, plain stitches).

How can this be resolved?

This young lady says press on foot pedal slowly, but it is still going fast. It doesn't sound so loud. Perhaps the video is not capturing how loud it is.

Or is it a matter of comfort and getting used to. Please help!!!!

https://youtu.be/xdHnrlrQ6RE?t=353

Comment: Consider the following test: remove all threads from the machine to avoid making knots. Gently press the foot pedal. Listen/observe the speed. Press more on the pedal. Does the speed increase or does it remain at the first level? If it does not get faster, but runs the same speed, your foot pedal may be defective.

Comment: You can even test the pedal with your hand. Since most people are more dexterous with their hand than their feet, it's easier to see whether the machine reacts to different pressure levels of the pedal. Simply lay it on the table and gently press down with your hand until the machine starts the sewing motion. If the machine always runs on full speed, the pedal is probably broken. If not, consider using it barefoot or turned around (back side facing you).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Singer foot pedals sometimes have a speed adjustment.  Mine does, I own a CG 550. Look underneath the pedal and if there is a little hole, you should be able to take an electronics grade small flat head screwdriver or one for glasses and torque the gauge to speed up or slow down. 
[image: underside of foot pedal]
Singer machines typically come at middle speed. As this is a beginner machine, it may already be set as slow as it goes. Of course, that is, if it even has the speed adjustment slot.

My very first Singer had the hole with the ability to adjust the speed without the markings. 
[image: small screwdriver]

You’re machine manual on page 6, states that speed is only controlled by your foot. See pic from manual taken from Singer website.
[image: singer manual]

Yes, you can control the speed of a consumer machine somewhat. Mostly it feels like slow, fast and stop. Commercial machines have much more subtle control.
The best way to get used to the speed of your  oops, sewing machine is to take gobs of scrap fabric and go nuts with all the stitches. It’s fun and helps.

Comment: And if you don't have an adjustment, it might be possible to tape a small block of wood or similar to the back of the pedal that would keep you from being able to depress it fully.

Comment: I just adjusted mine, a heavy duty singer model, but found that the + setting was the slowest and the - setting was the fastest!

Comment: @Graham Welcome to Arts & Crafts.  This definitely isn't proper operation.  One possibility is that the control got turned 180 degrees.  This can happen if it was serviced and reassembled in the wrong orientation, or the adjuster is held in place with a nut and the control was turned hard enough to rotate it.  It's still working relative to turning it clockwise vs. counter-clockwise, but the pointer is now on the opposite side of the labeling or the unmarked slot is upside-down so it looks like it's moving toward the wrong symbol.

Answer (score 2):

The sewing machine in the clip you've linked to is going very slowly; it seems as though you have no familiarity with machine sewing, have chosen to jump in without knowledge or training, and are uncomfortable with the machine. You also mention not knowing how to thread the machine or perform the most basic function of it.

There is no way to slow a basic machine beyond pressing gently on the foot pedal; some higher-end machines will have a stitch speed regulator, but these do not drop the speed any further than the clip in the linked video. **What needs to be addressed is your own comfort level.**

Return to the place where you purchased the machine and, instead of asking about speed, ask about classes. Many places will offer them, and frequently they'll be free if you've purchased a machine from them. Even if they don't offer them, they'll know where to direct you to take a class and learn how to use your machine. Due to your lack of experience, you have no confidence or comfort around the machine, are confused about how it works, and don't know where to start; **an in-person class is the best way to handle this extreme lack of comfort.** They'll be able to show you how to thread your particular machine and help you directly to get over your fear of it; after a good class, you should be able to easily sew simpler items confidently, with no fear of the "speed and noise" of your machine.

Answer (score 1):

I gave  my friend a dimmer box, originally used for a light. It slows the sewing machine down however much she wants.

Comment: This is actually how the foot pedals on many models work anyway. On an old simple machine, it should be fine, though any built-in light would get dimmer. Many modern machines would be damaged by being run off such a controller. The power supply for the electronics expects to see unmodified mains voltage

Comment: This will often work, but you need to be careful.  Some dimmers work by reducing the voltage, some work by chopping up the line voltage and passing through brief bursts so the load is getting voltage only a fraction of the time (and at a higher frequency).  Some types of motors will do fine within limits, some will overheat with the "wrong" type of controller, which can shorten the life of the sewing machine.

Answer (score 0):

Many sewing machines are designed with adjustable speed, but some of them may not be very sensitive. You can easily adjust the sewing speed from the screens of the sewing machines produced today and continue sewing instantly.  On some sewing machines, this setting is positioned at the bottom so that you can adjust it with a screwdriver.
If you are looking for a sewing machine that can adjust the speed well, I use the Brother SE1900, and recommend it.